# Convert string to correct date format in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a long list of dates that are in formats:`YYYY-MM-DD` or `DD/MM/YYYY`. I use `CDate()` for conversion. However, if system default date is `YYYY-MM-DD`, I get wrong dates converted from `DD/MM/YYYY` where Day and Month gets mixed up if Day is less than 13. For example:

```
date_string = "12/02/2016"
date_string = Cdate(date_string)
Debug.Print date_string #prints "2016-12-02"
```

I understand that `CDate()` largely depends on system and string format. I was wondering if there's a good way to capture day and month and do correct conversion? The list always includes only two mentioned date formats.

Comment: Use `Split` and `DateSerial` to rebuild the dates in an unambiguous fashion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @Rory the following function should do the trick:

```
Function ConvertDate(strTMP As String)

Select Case True
    Case InStr(1, strTMP, "-", vbTextCompare) > 0
        ConvertDate = DateSerial(Split(strTMP, "-")(0), Split(strTMP, "-")(1), Split(strTMP, "-")(2))
    Case InStr(1, strTMP, "/", vbTextCompare) > 0
        ConvertDate = DateSerial(Split(strTMP, "/")(2), Split(strTMP, "/")(1), Split(strTMP, "/")(0))
    Case Else
        ConvertDate = "error"
End Select

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess there is no way around but to create rules for each date format.

Comment: @Trm: actually, I gave you only a small piece of the function I have essentially created for myself. That function is able to "recognize" and convert and kind of date format incl. `.` and `-` and `/` and any given order `YYYYMMDD` or `MMDDYYYY` (US) or `YYYYDDMM` (RU) etc. to a valid date. Furthermore, it allows to enter numbers only which will also get converted to dates. For example 14 = the date two weeks from now or -30 = the date 30 days ago etc. The function grew over the years. But it is very much worth it and nobody wants a date-picker anymore.

Comment: how do you tell between `YYYYMMDD` and `YYYYDDMM`? Asuming month and day is 0-12

Comment: With `.` I give a preference towards `DD.MM.YYYY` with `/` as separator the preference is towards `MM/DD/YYYY`. Without any separators (or `-` as separator) ISO format `YYYYMMDD` is assumed. If that doesn't work then local computer settings are used (unless overwritten by DB preferences, as I have an SQL backend storing individual user preferences). I used the following as a primary guideline: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country